# Creating a csv with columns for each header

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Hello this is my code,

```
import pandas as pd

liste= [{'Urun_No':'Urun1','Adet':10},
{'Urun_No':'Urun1','Adet':10}]
df.columns = ['Urun_No','Adet']    
df_download_stoklar= pd.DataFrame(liste)
df_download_stoklar.to_csv('deneme.csv',index=False,header=True)
```

It places data in one column.

[image]

How can I set a column for each header?
[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly? Above code should create a dataframe with two columns named 'Urun_No' and 'Adet'

Comment: It looks like this on the file, in  one column :                                                                 Urun_No,Adet
Urun1,10

Comment: can you provide a sample expected output

Comment: on the file,in two different columns

Comment: @ThaminduDJ I edited the question with images

Comment: It might be due to the application you're opening the csv file. Try with different software (eg: notepad++, excel software, vscode). Or else try loading the csv file using python code. If it loads the dataframe correctly, nothing wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

What is the output you expect?

In your list of dictionaries "liste" you provied 2 columns with values "Urun1" and "10"

This would give me the following dataframe:

```
liste= [{'Urun_No':'Urun1','Adet':10},
{'Urun_No':'Urun1','Adet':10}]
columns = ['Urun_No','Adet']    
df_download_stoklar= pd.DataFrame(liste, columns=columns)
df_download_stoklar.to_csv('deneme.csv',index=False,header=True)
```

output:

```
    Urun_No Adet
0   Urun1   10
1   Urun1   10
```